# pyopengl faults in glGenTextures

Tags: python, opengl, segmentation-fault

i have this problem:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from OpenGL.GL import *
>>> glGenTextures
<OpenGL.lazywrapper.glGenTextures object at 0x9d3b18c>
>>> glGenTextures(1)
Segmentation fault
```

i'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

what can it be? where can i find some other info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to make a context active before calling any OpenGL functions.  Also, `glGenTextures` needs two parameters, so pyopengl isn't calling it directly.  You'd have to look at the pyopengl source code to see exactly what's going wrong, but creating a context first is sure to be part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An OpenGL context needs to be created before gl.glGenTextures can be called.

Example code:

```
import OpenGL.GLUT as glut
import OpenGL.GL as gl

# Init glut
glut.glutInit(())
glut.glutInitDisplayMode(
    glut.GLUT_RGBA | glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | glut.GLUT_ALPHA | glut.GLUT_DEPTH | glut.GLUT_MULTISAMPLE
)
glut.glutInitWindowSize(40, 40)
glut.glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
window = glut.glutCreateWindow("title_of_the_window")

# Generate Texture Names
gl.glGenTextures(1)
```